# How to convert this python 3 code to python 2.7?

Tags: python

I can write very basic level of python. I found this python 3 script ( argv 1 and 2 are input.txt and output.txt):

```
import sys
inf = open (sys.argv[1],  'r')
ouf = open (sys.argv[2],  'w')

def summarize(data:list, crit:float, run:int)->list:
    i = 0
    s = []
    while i < len(data):
        j = i
        while (j < len(data)) and (crit <= data[j]):
            j += 1
        if run <= j - i:
            s.append('{}-{}'.format(i+1, j))
        i = j+1
    return s

def transfer(head:str, data:list, sink:open, crit:float, run:int)->None:

    summary = summarize(data, crit, run)
    if summary:
        sink.write('{}: {}\n'.format(head, ', '.join(summary)))

def collect(source:open, sink:open, crit:float = 0.5, run:int = 1)->None:

    data = head = []
    for line in source:
        L = line.strip()
        if not L.startswith('#'):
            data.append(float(L.split()[-1]))
        else:
            transfer(head, data, sink, crit, run)
            data = []
            head = L[1:].strip()
    transfer(head, data, sink, crit, run)

collect(inf, ouf)
inf.close()
ouf.close()
```

that converts a (input.txt) file such as:

```
# IUPred 
# Copyright (c) Zsuzsanna Dosztanyi, 2005
#
# Z. Dosztanyi, V. Csizmok, P. Tompa and I. Simon
# J. Mol. Biol. (2005) 347, 827-839. 
#
#
# Prediction output 
# NP_414578.2
    1 M     0.4476
    2 S     0.5286
    3 E     0.7328
    4 S     0.8019
    5 L     0.2094
    6 H     0.2503
    7 L     0.1791
    8 T     0.9193
# IUPred 
# Copyright (c) Zsuzsanna Dosztanyi, 2005
#
# Z. Dosztanyi, V. Csizmok, P. Tompa and I. Simon
# J. Mol. Biol. (2005) 347, 827-839. 
#
#
# Prediction output 
# NP_418290.4
    1 M     0.5328
    2 E     0.8759
    3 S     0.5323
    4 W     0.1942
    5 L     0.2575
    6 I     0.8823
    7 P     0.8034
    8 A     0.2258
    9 A     0.2541
    10 P     0.8783
    11 V     0.1002
    12 T     0.3583
```

to a (output.txt) file as:

```
NP_414578.2: 2-4, 8-8
NP_418290.4: 1-3, 6-7, 10-10
```

That is, it lists the ranges (first column) whose values are >= 0.5 in last column.

The fact is, this will be a ideal supporting scripts for parsing my data which are generated using pre-published python software packages written in python2. To add it with those pre-existing tools, I need to convert the above script to python2.

I try to use py3to2, but it doesn't give any different script.

Please suggest how can I convert it to python 2.

Thank you

Comment: Here's a wild idea: try running it on Python 2 and check if it works. It doesn't? Use your favourite search engine to check for solutions, try fixing it yourself. Didn't work? Post the problem here. Hint: take a closer look how Python 2 and 3 handle files.

Comment: just remove the explicit types in the methods' signatures

Comment: It shows following error then I  run with py2.7:File "script.py", line 5
    def summarize(data:list, crit:float, run:int)->list:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You don't really need a tool to convert the script. Just go through the errors one by one. To start with, Python 2 doesn't have argument typing.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, what I am trying to do is removing annotations as suggested by Carsoso, as: def summarize(data, crit, run):  'e' ... but i'm still struggling with it

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by all of you..I finally end up in this:

```
import sys
inf = open (sys.argv[1],  'r')
ouf = open (sys.argv[2],  'w')


def summarize(data, crit, run):
    'e'
    i = 0
    s = []
    while i < len(data):
        j = i
        while (j < len(data)) and (crit <= data[j]):
            j += 1
        if run <= j - i:
            s.append('{}-{}'.format(i+1, j))
        i = j+1
    return s

def transfer(head, data, sink, crit, run):
    'et'

    summary = summarize(data, crit, run)
    if summary:
        sink.write('{}: {}\n'.format(head, ', '.join(summary)))

def collect(source, sink, crit = 0.5, run = 1):
    'etc'

    data = head = []
    for line in source:
        L = line.strip()
        if not L.startswith('#'):
            data.append(float(L.split()[-1]))
        else:
            transfer(head, data, sink, crit, run)
            data = []
            head = L[1:].strip()
    transfer(head, data, sink, crit, run)

collect(inf, ouf)
inf.close()
ouf.close()
```

Seems like it works. Please let me know if there there is anything creepy.

Thank you all